# Sum involving 2nd antiderivative of the digamma function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, closed-form, digamma-function, polygamma

Help evaluate the following sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n-1}\ln\left(2n-1\right)+\frac{4}{\left(4n-1\right)\left(4n-3\right)}\left(\psi^{(-2)}\left(2n-\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi^{(-2)}\left(2n-1\right)\right)\right)$$

This arose from a relation to an integral.

We could try to find a form for the partial sums and take the limit. How would we go about that?

**Update**

I found an equivalent form as follows
$$\frac{\pi}{8}\left(6\ln A+\ln\pi-\frac{1}{6}\ln2-1\right)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln\left(4n+2\right)}{\left(4n+1\right)}+\frac{2}{\left(4n+1\right)\left(4n+3\right)}\sum_{k=1}^{4n+2}\left(-1\right)^{\left(k+1\right)}k\ln\left(k\right)\right)$$

Comment: What makes you think it has a closed form?

Comment: I don’t know, but I am hoping.

Comment: Note that by definition: $$\psi^{(-2)} (z)=\int_0^z \log \Gamma(t) dt$$

And:

$$\int _{0}^{z}\log \Gamma (t)\,dt={\frac {z(1-z)}{2}}+{\frac {z}{2}}\log 2\pi +z\log \Gamma (z)-\log G(1+z)$$

Where $G$ is [Barnes function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function).